# Is np.random.choice supposed to coerce?

Tags: python, numpy, random, coercion

I just noticed that if np.random.choice is used on a list that contains both strings and integers, then when integers are returned, they are coerced to strings. Is this intended behavior?

e.g.

`>>>numpy.random.choice([1,2,3,4])
1`

but

`>>>numpy.random.choice(['a',1,2,3,4])
'1'`

I guess I can do `my_list[np.random.choice(range(len(my_list)))]`, but that seems rather ugly.

Comment: I suspect it's because it needs to return a uniform array if you specify `size > 1`, so it coerces everything to a common type before choosing.

Comment: Does this happen if you use the regular `random.choice` instead of `numpy`?

Comment: It is indeed supposed to coerce, since NumPy will want to work with fixed arrays with identical-type elements; that's why it exists. Normally, `numpy.random.choice` works on an array, and otherwise it will first convert its input to an array before proceeding. Which is what happens here.

Comment: Just use `import random; random.choice(['a',1,2,3,4])` why are you even using `numpy` with `list` objects?

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga I want to get a weighted random choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to random choice; NumPy methods work with NumPy arrays, and if given a Python list, they will convert it to an array before doing anything else. The conversion results in:

```
>>> np.array(['a', 1, 2, 3, 4])
array(['a', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

an array of one-character Unicode strings. The choice is made from this array.